# Do WMI (ManagementObjectSearcher) queries require elevated trust?

Tags: c#, permissions, windows-services, wmi

So I need to find my configured DNS servers.

I do a WMI lookup with [`ManagementObjectSearcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.aspx) on [`Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This works well in development. Will it still work when running as a service under a lesser privileged account (e.g. `NETWORK SERVICE`)?

Answer (score 1):

From the [section of "MSDN titled Access to WMI Namespaces"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa822575%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The default access permissions for the Authenticated Users, LOCAL
>   SERVICE, and NETWORK SERVICE are:
>
> - Execute Methods
> - Full Write
> - Enable Account

Note that [you might not have access to some functions if your process isn't running in elevated security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa826699%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Also note that [some operations require raised privileges as well](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (particularly when dealing with security descriptors).

Answer (score 1):

Security and WMI are fairly restricted, I believe you're referring to `ImpersonationLevel` & `AuthenticationLevel` settings. Remote WMI is even more tricky but take a look at:

Impersonation Level: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393852(v=vs.85).aspx

Authentication Level: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393851(v=vs.85).aspx

Something along the lines of the following can be used to elevate elevate permissions for WMI (in VBS and CMD) and retrieve DNS settings so I'd assume you can do the same in other languages:

**VBS**

```
Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,authenticationLevel=pktPrivacy}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set oQRY.ExecQuery("select DcSiteName,DnsForestName,DomainName from Win32_NTDomain")`
```

**CMD**

```
wmic /implevel:Impersonate /authlevel:Pktprivacy /namespace:\\root\cimv2 path win32_ntdomain get /all /format:list
```